# What does Watson Assistant use to check regex?

Tags: regex, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to use entities to get a match on some data, and the regex seems like it doesn't really match well with other similar engines in Python or even sites like regexr.com. Here some examples:

Pattern: `([\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}-[\w]{3})`

String style to match: 83123e42-d9ad-a26a-b13f-b0ec91c7fedf-ABC

However, when testing this out, it gets:

`@id:83123e42`

`@id:d9ad`

`@id:a26a`

`@id:b13f`

`@id:b0ec91c7fedf`

`@id:ABC`

I've tried grouping the whole string, using string delimiters, escaping the hypens, using `.{4}-` instead of \w, but all to no solid result, and often getting the exact same matching where it splits it into groups rather than one full match.

Is this a regex issue? I tried not grouping the whole string, but seem to keep running into the exact same issue, where it won't even find the last 3 letters anyway.

If Watson Assistant uses a different regex engine, is there a place with documentation that I just haven't been able to find? They seem to just assume that any normal regex will work, but skipping the hypens is strange behavior.

Comment: Your input is split with `-`. You should check the relevant documentation on how the string and the regex extraction results are used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Should I escape the `-`s then? So regex should be:

([\w]{8}\-[\w]{4}\-[\w]{4}\-[\w]{4}\-[\w]{12}\-[\w]{3})

That doesn't seem to capture the full group either

Comment: You should not escape a `-`  in any regex engine when outside of a charsacter class. Only in Lua patterns it must escaped.

Comment: Okay great, so then how would I capture the hypens properly to be able to have the entity return as @id:83123e42-d9ad-a26a-b13f-b0ec91c7fedf-ABC ?

Comment: Your pattern works ok for me in `WA` `@id.literal` returns the full matched id and  `@id.groups` returns the matched groups - if any defined.

Comment: @MichalBida Sorry, I don't think I understand. How would I get the `@id.literal` value? The `WA` json response is only grouped, there is no literal attribute, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: If you want to get the value in the JSON response you can create a variable `"my_id_literal" : "<?@id.literal?>"` <- just check the `@id` entity is recognized in the input.

Comment: @MichalBida So, that just comes back with `@id_literal = "a69986e1"`

Where the whole "id" sent in is: `a69986e1-3660-a52d-c967-444fd239dd02-ABC`

Comment: That is weird, because it comes correctly for me. What API version are you using? The latest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding a more direct answer from an awesome helper in the Slack channel:

Turns out that something in the Watson assistant Regex doesn't recognize hyphens.

He ended up working with me and showing me a bit of SpEL that I have running to assign to a context variable that I can then use.

`"<? input.text.extract('(\\w{8}\\-\\w{4}\\-\\w{4}\\-\\w{4}\\-\\w{12}\\-\\w{3}[^\\w]+)', 0) ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Citing the [Watson Assistant docs for defining entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities), here the relevant parts:

> The regular expression engine is loosely based on the Java regular
>   expression engine. The Watson Assistant service will produce an error
>   if you try to upload an unsupported pattern, either via the API or
>   from within the Watson Assistant service Tooling UI.

That section has some information on limitations and what to consider
 when writing regex expressions. The most significant cited are:

> Entity patterns may not contain:
>   - Positive repetitions (for example `x*+`)
>   - Backreferences (for example `\g1`)
>   - Conditional branches (for example `(?(cond)true)`)

Comment: So, I didn't use positive repetitions, backrefs, or conditional branches. And from what I've read about the Java regex engine, that pattern should have been fine. I see nothing about anything I'm doing in that pattern that would fail to recognize the full string.

Comment: Lookaheads and lookbehinds are not supported either in `WA` regexps.